# Meaning of the expression $\sigma_{k,k′}^{i,j}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, notation, computer-science

I have this paragraph in [this](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/b02c/6b00bd5dbdbd951fddb00b906c82fa80f0b3.pdf) research paper.

> Let $\sigma_{k,k′}^{i,j}$ be the sequence of messages $p_i$ sends to
>   $p_j$ during iteration $k$ of $p_i$ and $k′$ of $p_j$.

What kind of sequence $\sigma_{k,k′}^{i,j}$ is? How this mathematical expression is called ?

Is this a [double series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DoubleSeries.html) ?

Comment: Why have you given the tag as measure theory?

Comment: @SachchidanandPrasad please help me to choose correct tag

Comment: @JDoe Maybe you can add the `notation` tag.

Answer (score 1):

It is *not* a double series. This has nothing to do with summation. I wouldn't even call it calculus (therefore I removed that tag). It's rather discrete mathematics.

Therefore I don't think that this expression has a name in mathematics; it's a notation introduced in this paper just to have some notation for a sequence of messages between processes. It has the indices of the sender and receiver processes. It also has indices of in what iterations the messages are sent and received.